# jQuery fire page load event from loaded page

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-load

I'm loading a PHP page in a div with `$("#div").load("page.php?id-blah")`

The page gets loaded correctly and jQuery is functioning properly.

In the `page.php` I am using the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...perform things..
})
```

call but its not fired. What event do I have to use to make `perform` things run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's not good practice to inject scripts this way. You should look into dynamic loading frameworks (RequireJS, JSPM...).

Having said that, you could put your script in a normal `<script>` tag, and make sure that's the last part of the returned content. HTML parsing is sequential, so it will only be parsed after everything else is done.